# Issue with essurvey R package

Tags: r

I installed the `essurvey` R package and I'm following the documentation:

```
library(essurvey)

dk_three <- essurvey::import_country("Denmark", 1:3)
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

I tried to download the dev version on git but haven't had any luck. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: Have you registered an email address as described in the documentation?

Comment: The package doesn't work anymore (hopefully temporarily) because the ESS changed the way we could download the data: https://github.com/ropensci/essurvey/issues/56. The organization behind the package is currently looking for a maintainer that could implement the new way of getting the data: https://github.com/ropensci/essurvey/issues/57